# How can I extracting the last four pages from 1000+ pdfs in batch?

Tags: pdf, batch-processing

I have around 1000+ pdfs. I need to extract the last 4 pages of each document and then save each file.
What is the easiest way to do this?

I don't have access to Adobe Pro and the number of documents will require automation.

Answer (score 0):

Use you favourite shell or scripting language to call:

`cpdf in.pdf ~4-end -o out.pdf`

You may need to check that there are at least four pages in the file as well.